# How do I prepare for summer heat?

Tags: dont-starve, reign-of-giants

In the DLC *Reign of Giants*, summer now induces *overheating* (the opposite of winter's freezing) and before the summer comes, there are piles of ice on the map, much like and rock boulders, that you can mine. When the summer finally comes, these piles completely melt and the only way to cool off that I found is to wear a hat made out of watermelon and twigs.

[image] **→** [image]             [image] **→** [image]

I've seen the inverse-fireplace that I can craft using some nitre and electric doodads, but that is stationary and I want to be able to do some things during summer, but as it lasts **15 days**, I'm not sure I'll be able to without proper preparations.

[image] [image]

I thought I could just leave the top world for caves and stay there, but it's very difficult, since I didn't have any lighting gear and the light coming from the top world still induces overheating at about the same rate.

What resources do I need to have gathered to safely roam throughout the world in summer without the fear of overheating?

So far I've found that there are items that instantly reduce overheat value by a pre-set amount and can be used only a few times, and the items that constantly reduce overheating, but they spoil or break over time. Other methods require being stationary or within vicinity of some objects. I also found out that standing close to base (don't know which structures though) reduces overheating (maybe it's like trees, or maybe they absorb heat).

Answer (score 7):

Things that let you stay cool while moving:

Melon hat - slows overheating

Straw hat - slows overheating

being wet - slows overheating

Parasol or umbrella - slows overheating

Staying under trees where possible -slows overheating

Chilled Amulet - no overheating, must be micromanaged or you freeze

Ice Cube hat - no overheating, makes you wet

Thermal stone that has been placed in either a icebox or near an endothermic fire - no overheating till it runs out

Eating ice -lowers body temperature
Using a luxury fan -lowers body temperature

Comment: Eating ice just lowers your body temperature with 10 degrees. It doesn't reverse anything.

Comment: @Konerak what about those degrees? Is there a hidden meter?

Comment: In vanilla DS/ROG, the degrees are hidden. Mods like 'Always On' show all the basic values permanently (instead of only on hover) and add the temperature and naughtiness.

Comment: so it's not intended to be displayed originally, okay

Comment: @Konerak thats what I meant, it has an opposite effect.

Answer (score 2):

Summer is the same is winter: going away from base is hard due to temperature. Being stationary is easier, but boring. In my opinion, **the ice cube is the way to go**.

Lawton gave a good list of things that help. Let me add some advice:

## Prepare your base, just as you do for winter.

- Make sure you have a science machine & alchemy machine

## Get some much needed items

- Gears, for an ice box.
- Ice, atleast 10. Put it in the ice box.
- Gold and stone, for the ice cube and the endothermic fire pit.
- Gather enough rocks (atleast (2+5)*3 = 21) for the stationary
  endothermic fire pit.
- Grab some nitre while you're there.
- A thermal stone is recommended (as is for winter). Put it in the ice box.

## Secure a food supply

Summer, as winter, disables certain things. Grass & twigs will wither.