# Is there anything to do except surviving in the summer

Tags: dont-starve, reign-of-giants

During the summer, plants wither, stuff gets set on fire, you overheat... it's worse than winter ever was.

Two existing questions on this site answer how to prepare ([How do I prepare for summer heat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165037/how-do-i-prepare-for-summer-heat)) and how to survive ([Summer has come and I don't know what to do](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165767/summer-has-come-and-i-dont-know-what-to-do)), but none of those really answer my question:

### Is there anything to do, during summer, except survive?

During winter you can hunt mactusk, for the very desirable walking cane. You can chop ice, to prepare for summer. You gather pengull eggs & feathers, for gunpowder. Spring comes with frogs, rains (mushrooms!). Autumn is the calm season, without much threats, the easy one.

Offcourse, in every season, the purpose is to defeat the giant - but is there more to summer? **What can be done in summer that can't be (as easily) done during other seasons?**

Comment: I agree with you. I've found summer harder than winter, mainly because your camp is in constant danger of random fires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Don't Starve Wiki article](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Summer) for summer:

**The good**:

- Cacti will yield Cactus Flowers during the summer
- The days are longer, which makes fertilized crops grow fast longer 
  (but not as much as in the spring)

**The bad**:

- Plants wilt
- Food spoils 25% faster
- You get damage and can die from overheating
- There is a drought and things can combust
- Occasionally a dragonfly will roam around the land, setting things on fire as it goes

**So**, the answer to the question is: **not much**.

Comment: The cactus flower is a nice find, thanks! How dissapointing though, that the only thing to do during summer, is find stuff to help survive summer. I don't need 20 days for that, it gets very boring. Hope they fix that when it leaves beta, but I'm afraid they are focusing on multiplayer right now.

Comment: I think that's the focus of summer, to be hard. That's why you can prepare for summer in so many ways.

Comment: I guess so. I don't care if it's hard, but it's a shame that it's also boring. I think I'll just put a few tents,siesta-lean-to's and ice boxes in a desert, sleep through days, nights, eat, and maybe gather a few cactus flowers for the fun of it. Thanks for your answer!